# Creating DBUnit dataset with specified records

Tags: java, dataset, dbunit

I'm using DBUnit to create dataset that will contain only records with proper IDs.

```
Set ids = new HashSet();
ids.add(new BigDecimal(34552));
TablesDependencyHelper.getDataset(connection, "MYTABLE", ids);
```

But I get dataset that contains all the records from this table (+record from some dependent tables).

Also I'm confused about composite primary keys. For example, I have ID1 and ID2 columns as primary key - how to create dataset in this case (with specified records only)?

Comment: How are you defining your connection?

Comment: Conection is fine, thats for sure. I create JDBC connection then I create DBUnit connect with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I realize that the only way to do it with DBUnit is:

```
QueryDataSet queryDataSet = new QueryDataSet(connection);
queryDataSet.addTable("MYTABLE", "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID=34552");
```